# Incorrect imposing of shadows

Tags: opengl-es, webgl, shadow

In case of creation of shadows on object there are unnecessary shadows:
[image: NOOOO]
example: https://webgl-project-toly19.c9.io/index.html

It is made by an example with http://codeflow.org/

P.S. `float bias = 0.001;`

Answer (score 0):

First adjust the shadow texture parameters as below

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

Then try adjusting light camera's near value and shadow bias as both are mutually dependent.